# Can't delete or update documents in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am able to create documents with the help of Mongoose in Node.js, but not able to update or delete them.

I tried doing it on the terminal with the following command:

```bash
db.news.updateOne({name: 'Mishra'}, {$set :{name:'mishra'}})
```

Here's the code I have tried, but it doesn't work:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/newDB');

const newSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number
});

const user = mongoose.model('new', newSchema);

const newUser = new user({
    name: 'Sharabh',
    age: 22
});

// Uncomment to check if user exists
// console.log(Boolean(user.find({name: 'Mishra'})))

user.updateOne({name: 'Mishra'}, {$set: {name: 'mishra'}});

// Uncomment to save
// user.save();
// newUser.save();
```

Comment: I know i added sharabh in the name but i did change it from the terminal. so thats not the problem. and also the boolean console returns true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `user.updateOne()` method is an asynchronous task. You need to wait for the task to complete.

If you are using [Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) (i.e `import` statements) then you can do a top level `await`:

```
const result = await user.updateOne({name: 'Mishra'},{$set: {name: 'mishra'}});
```

Or if you are using [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules-commonjs-modules) (i.e `require` statements) then you can do:

```
user.updateOne({name: 'Mishra'},{$set: {name: 'mishra'}})
.then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
})
.catch((err) => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

If this is going to be in a post request  from a form you submit then you can mark the callback function as `async` then use `await` in the update like so:

```
const user = mongoose.model('new', newSchema)
app.post('/', async (req, res, next) => { // < Note the use of async
   try {
       const updated = { // < Get the data from your form post
          name: req.body.name,
          age: req.body.age
       }
       const result = await user.updateOne({name: 'Mishra'},{$set: updated});
       console.log(result);
       res.status(201).json({
          updatedUser : result
       });
   } catch(err) {
      next(err);
   }
});
```